# Error in JSON encode

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have a problem when encode an NSMutableArray *array* of custom object (Room).
My custom object is : -nameRoom (NSString) -numberRoom (NSInteger).

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This is the error:
*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (Room)*

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/dataWithJSONObject:options:error:) (yes, sometimes reading the documentation is helpful)

> You use the NSJSONSerialization class to convert JSON to Foundation
>   objects and convert Foundation objects to JSON.
>
> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following
>   properties:
>
> - The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
> - All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.
> - All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
> - Numbers are not NaN or infinity.
>
> Other rules may apply. Calling isValidJSONObject: or attempting a
>   conversion are the definitive ways to tell if a given object can be
>   converted to JSON data.

Comment: Reading the documentation: tl;d; This is the Internet tutorials, Git & SO generation.

Comment: for several years I thought `tl;dr` were malformed html-entities and wondering why they appeared everywhere till a significant younger colleague told me, what it means. One of the first "Now I am old" moments I had.

Comment: Same here, I was way behind. But, I'll wager you are young compared to me. ;-)

Comment: old enough for counting bit/s as baud, not old enough for a stylish Borsalino.

Comment: OK, I want a Borsalino! I started out as a HW designer with–wait for it–vacuum tubes. Then punch cards and paper tape for the binary.

Comment: I have a stack of punch cards at home. Still waiting that I get computation time. But the administrator isn't answering my calls for the last couple of dozen years.

Answer (score 1):

JSON does not support custom objects.

See: [Introducing JSON](http://json.org).

In order to support a custom object you will have to break it down into a graph of standard JSON objects. In the OP's case it will simply be a dictionary containing `nameRoom` and `numberRoom`.